# Having files separate for development

Tags: brunch

Is it possible with Brunch from brunch.io to not combine all the files into one app.js?

I find it very helpful to see the name of the script if an error occurs, but I wasn't able to configure it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you cannot force brunch to compile files one-by-one.

You can concatenate to some exact number of files, though. See [docs](http://brunch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#files).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and taking care of the community!